# Play a file after calling getPath in Java

Tags: java, string, file

The return value of a value from getPath() from the File Class is something like this

```
"C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\ASDF.mp3".
```

To use the Desktop class from java to play a file, the path would have to be fed into a file, with a path similar to

```
"C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\ASDF.mp3"
```

Since the \ is a reserved character(From my understanding) to make a new file you must use a double backslash to dictate that it is a file. My problem is that when I try to get the path I need to transform it into a double slash version. The .replaceAll() method doesn't allow for '\' since it's a reserved character but the .replace() method does.

To work around this would I just have to loop through to find all instances and replace them one at a time? Or is there a simpler work around? Also I would like to know if I am receiving this error due to it being a reserved character, or if I am completely wrong.

Comment: message = message.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
replace - takes in a substring and replaceAll takes in a regex, hence the difference. \\ is the regex for \ but with java's escape character the number of \ doubles.

Answer (score 0):

The two strings above are actually exactly the same.
When Java or other language outputs a string it only displays one slash '\', but when you are typing the string into double quotes you need double backslash '\\' so the Java parser knows it's one slash. Backslash is used for many other escape characters, so this is only way parser will know.
(Even when typing this answer, I needed 4 backslashes to make only 2!

Comment: So I just need to add a preceding '\' character and I should be fine? Also I cannot vote your response. But thank you.

Comment: @user1241388 you don't need to replace \'s existing string only when adding new text e.g: path+"\\file.txt";